# Debugging third-party C library used by application written in C

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, alsa

I faced some trouble when developing my application in C  and could not find a reason. So I need some advice about how to debug native application which uses 3rd party libraries.

I'm developing sound application under Linux with `alsa` and the function applying configuration returns negative value with some error code http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga1ca0dc120a484965e26cabf966502330

```
snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
//configuring 
snd_pcm_hw_params(snd_pcm_t*, snd_pcm_hw_params_t); //returns negative value... How to troubleshoot?
```

Is it possible to step into a function of a 3rd party library which I did not build? If so what do I need to do this? Do I need to download a source code and attach it somewhow to IDE or gdb?

The perfect case is that I could step through the function and understand under which condition the negative value is returned.

Is something like this possible in C programming universe?

Comment: What is your linux distribution?

Comment: @ks1322 Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You need a build of the library with debug symbols and preferably minimal or no optimisation. Since alsa is open source it is very easy to build it, but there might be an even easier way. Your Linux distro may provide debugging symbols for the library in a separate package, e.g. alsa-dbg or similar. It doesn't replace the binary itself with an unoptimised version, so you may observe some erratic jumping around the source code in gdb, and some variables will be unavailable. This may or may not be a big problem for you. Try it and see.

Comment: BTW what exactly the "// configuring" line stands for, and what negative value is returned?

Comment: @n.m. By configuring I meant setting configuration parameters, i.e. samle rate, stream (for capturing), number of channels, period size (in frames), periods and sample format. The behavior is not stable actually. Sometimes Im getting the error (negative value) with incorrect buffer size when setting the buffer size earlier then applying the configuration. Sometimes `snd_pcm_readi` returns negative (strace shows no syscalls). Probably this is sort of UB. Im a beginner in C programming so Im curious about the way of troubleshooting issues with 3rd party libs like this one...

Comment: Note that errors you encounter using third-party libraries are usually attributable to misuse.  Although yes, you can step into third-party library code with your debugger (even *without* the debug symbols, though that's typically unhelpful), you should start by focusing on your own code surrounding the call, and especially the arguments to the call.  And your debugger can surely step over library function calls instead of stepping into them if you so instruct it.

Comment: This function calls into the kernel, so forget about debugging. It might be a good idea to look up the part of the documentation labelled [Error Handling](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___error.html), but you could just ask what the error means.

Comment: @CL. the function does several things and probably calls into the kernel more than once. It is still helpful to know where exactly it fails.

Comment: @n.m. Maybe you have an idea why the `snd_pcm_hw_params(snd_pcm_t*, snd_pcm_hw_params_t);` may return -22. My first thought was that some parameter I set was invalid, but I checked all of them wit `snd_pcm_hw_params_test` and got the `0` value (except `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_rate(pcm_handle, hwparams, 44100, 0)`, it returns `-22` after the rate is actually set, but before it also returns 0).

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `-22` is `-EINVAL`. Some parameter is not supported by your device. What is the output of `aplay -D devicename --dump-hw-params`?

Comment: @n.m. I wrote a minimal example I can reproduce this issue. Could you please take a brief look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590158/unable-to-apply-configured-parameters-for-a-sound-device ?

Comment: @CL. I have a thought that I'm experiencing some sort of UB... Because the behavior of the program is affected by some unrelated part.