# Unable to apply configured parameters for a sound device

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, alsa

I wrote the following simple example with `asoundlib.h`:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct sound_device_config_t sound_device_config_t;

struct sound_device_config_t{
        unsigned int rate;
        unsigned int periods;
        snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size;
        unsigned int channels;
        snd_pcm_format_t sample_format;
};

static void _configure_device(snd_pcm_t **pcm_handle_ptr, const char *sd);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    sound_device_config_t *cfg_ptr = malloc(sizeof(sound_device_config_t));
    cfg_ptr -> channels = 2;
    cfg_ptr -> period_size = 2048;
    cfg_ptr -> periods = 2;
    cfg_ptr -> rate = 44100;
    cfg_ptr -> sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;

    _configure_device(&pcm_handle, "plughw:1,0");
    return 0;
}
```

Where the `_configure_device` is implemented at the end of the `main.c` file as follows:

```
static void _configure_device(snd_pcm_t **pcm_handle_ptr, const char *sd_name){ 
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hwparams;
    snd_pcm_stream_t stream = SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE;
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle = *pcm_handle_ptr;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&hwparams);
    const char * device_name = strdup(sd_name);

    int err;

    if((err = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, device_name, stream, 0)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong. Result code = %d\n", err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    }


    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcm_handle, hwparams)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Initialization failed wit error %d\n", err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    }
    int rate = 44100;
    int exact_rate;

    int direction;

    int periods = 2;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size = 8192;

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle, hwparams, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0){
       fprintf(stderr, "Error setting access. Details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
       return;
    } else {
        printf("Setting access to SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcm_handle, hwparams, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting format. Details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    } else {
        printf("Setting format to SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

    exact_rate = rate;
    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcm_handle, hwparams, &exact_rate, &direction)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting sample rate to %d. Details: %s\n", exact_rate, snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    } else if(rate != exact_rate){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "The rate %d is not supported by your hardware.\n\
        Setting rate to the nearest supported %d instead.\n", rate, exact_rate);
    } else {
        printf("Setting rate to %d: %s\n", rate, snd_strerror(err));
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, hwparams, 2))){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting number of channels. Details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    } else {
        printf("Setting channels to 2: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods(pcm_handle, hwparams, periods, direction))){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting periods to %d. Details: %s\n", periods, snd_strerror(err));
        return; 
    } else {
        printf("Setting periods to %d: %s\n", periods, snd_strerror(err));
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size(pcm_handle, hwparams, (period_size * periods) >> 2)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting buffer size. Details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    } else {
        printf("Setting buffer size status: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

    if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcm_handle, hwparams)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set the configured params. Details: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return;
    } else {
        printf("Params are successfully applied to the pcm device\n");
    }
}
```

And it does not work. The following is printed when I run this code:

```
Setting access to SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED: Success
Setting format to SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE: Success
Setting rate to 44100: Success
Setting channels to 2: Success
Setting periods to 2: Success
Error setting buffer size. Details: Invalid argument
```

But, when I delete the config allocation and initialization of `sound_device_config_t` (which I intended to use for configuring sound device and currently does not use) it works completely fine:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;

    _configure_device(&pcm_handle, "plughw:1,0");
}
```

prints

```
Setting access to SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED: Success
Setting format to SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE: Success
Setting rate to 44100: Success
Setting channels to 2: Success
Setting periods to 2: Success
Setting buffer size status: Success
Params are successfully applied to the pcm device
```

This looks like some magic. I deleted the allocation of an object which is not used anywhere and it affects the program behavior.

Maybe I missed some UB here?

Comment: You requested an exact buffer size but Alsa cannot use just any random buffer size. Try `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near`, Alsa will then use the nearest correct value. `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_buffer_size` checks if this buffer size is available.

Comment: @n.m. "By trying and failing" I figured out that I did not set the value to the variable `int direction`. After I set it to 0 it started working. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: No :( Just shooting in the dark. But it's a reasonable requirement that direction should always be set.

Comment: If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. It's mean that `direction` can have any value I think it can make such behavior, but not sure.